# Extension methods for Object but not derived classes

Tags: c#, extension-methods

It's possible to make a extension method for Object but not being able to use it on any derived class?

What a want is some general utilities to convert objects to certain types handling common exceptions. Ej. method for converting object to string but changing null to empty string and trimming white spaces.

```
object obj = ...
// I want to use de the method when the object is 'casted' as 'object':
string strValue = obj.ToStringTrim();
// But not be able to use it in any subclass. Ej. en this string:
strValue.ToStringTrim();
```

I know this is a tricky syntactic sugar and I supose the answer will be negative, and I should make a custom utility class for this kind of conversions, but just curious if it's possible...

**EDIT**

I know this is against inheritance, but I just wanted a hack, syntactic sugar or whatever... And already exists some in C# ;). And, why is this an issue? Well, it's not really an issue, but I don't want to have so much bloat on the autocomplete

Comment: The question is unclear. *All* classes are objects. The `Object` class itself can't contain data, so there's no reason to use `ToStringTrim()`. The only result from that call can only be `System.Object`

Comment: Note: Extension methods are only available in source files where you import their namespace. (Probably doesn't help much in this case without forcing unwanted changes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not possible because that's not how inheritance works. A string is an Object. Period!
But why is that an issue? Don't use this extension with a string if you don't want.

However, the extension method could be implemented as:

```
public static string ToStringTrim(this Object obj)
{
    return obj?.ToString().Trim() ?? "";
}
```

If `obj` is already a `string` then this is a no-op because [`String.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_ToString) is implemented as `return this`.

Comment: I know this is against inheritance, but I just wanted a hack, syntactic sugar or whatever... And already exists some in C# ;). And, why is this an issue? Well, it's not really an issue, but I don't want to have so much bloat on the autocomplete.

Comment: @cag: then don't provide an extension method for `System.Object` and/or don't add the extension to every class in your solution.

Comment: I'll wait a one or two days to see if there is some magic. If it's not I'll accept your answer.